# Express socket.io to netty socket.io in spring

Tags: spring, express, socket.io, netty

I need to stream data from my backend (in spring) to my angular frontend.
I cant get the netty socket.io implementation working.

```
public ConnectListener onUserConnectWithSocket = new ConnectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnect(SocketIOClient socketIOClient) {
            log.info("Client connected: " + socketIOClient.getSessionId());
            socketIOClient.sendEvent("getAllDashboardData", generateRandomValues());
        }
    };

public DataListener<String> getAllDashboardData = new DataListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onData(SocketIOClient socketIOClient, String message, AckRequest ackRequest) throws Exception {
            log.info("Message received: " + message);
            socketIOClient.sendEvent("getAllDashboardData", generateRandomValues().toString());
        }
    };
```

when i have something like this, the EventListener never gets called (does not log User requested data). Hence, the onConnect logs that the frontend connected.

I tried out the frontend call using express!
This simple examples works perfect:

```
module.exports = (io) => {
    io.on('connect', (socket) => {
        console.log('user connected');
        socket.on('getAllDashboardData', (data) => {
            //send some data to client back
            socket.emit('getAllDashboardData', {data: 'data'});
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });
    });
}
```

how could i write this in spring?
I also tested the backend with postman and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const io = require('socket.io-client');
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {

  socket: any;
  readonly uri = 'ws://localhost:8085';

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.uri);
  }

  listen(eventName: string) {
    return new Observable((resolve) => {
      this.socket.on(eventName, (data: any) => {
       // this.socket.emit(eventName, data); maybe don't use this produces 1000 of calls
        resolve.next(data);
      });
    });
  }

  emit(eventName: string, data: any) {
    this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
  }
}
```

and use socket.io-client version 2.3.0 to work with netty spring.